# Get <div> as DOM object using selenium

Tags: selenium-rc, xpath

I am using selenium rc and exetuing

```
selenium.getText("//div/div[2][contains(@id,'gp-PACKAGE NAME-')]/div["+i+"]/table/tbody/tr/td["+1+"]/div")
```

I have to execute this command for 20-30 rows for which it takes 20-30 mins. I would like to get dom object for the table and parse it using java rather than executing `selenium.getText` for each row.

My expectation is that, I get dom object for all the rows from selenium and perform xpath query outside selenium using some dom parser.

Comment: just performing a getText on a single page 20-30 times should never take 20-30 mins. Is there more to this problem than just this?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you already know what xpath parsing engine you want to use, you could always pass it the HTML of //div/div[2][contains(@id,'gp-PACKAGE NAME-')] and then do what ever you wanted to do to it.

To do that all you need is to grab the html using Javascript and [getEval](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#executing-javascript-from-your-test):

```
selenium.getEval("var document = selenium.browserbot.getcurrentwindow().document;" +
    "var xpathResults = document.evaluate('//div/div[2][contains(@id,\"gp-PACKAGE NAME-\")]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);" +
    "var element = xpathResults.iterateNext();" +
    "var innerHtml = element.innerHTML;"
);
```